# Having trouble with computing Taylor Series with python Sympy

Tags: python

I want to compute the first 3 Taylor series for the function:
`f(x) = e^{-x^2} \sin( x - \pi)`.
I write like this. But got an error message: `cannot convert expression to float`. How can I fix this?

```py
import sympy
import math
sympy.init_printing(pretty_print=True)
x = sympy.Symbol('x')
f = math.exp(-x**2)*sin(x-(math.pi))
f.series(x0=math.pi, n=3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `math` methods instead of `sympy` methods. Try:

```
f = sympy.exp(-x**2)*sympy.sin(x-(sympy.pi))
```